# paypal possibility of classic API key coexist with REST API credential

Tags: api, rest, paypal, nvp

I am working on a project to upgrade an existing payment processing tool, which is using paypal's classic NVP api. Now, I need to program a whole new system that uses the PayPal's REST API and the two systems should share the same paypal account. Here is the question--if I create a REST API credential, will paypal disable my old classic NVP/SOAP API's key (or credential)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both at the same time without any problem.